# "just because… doesn't mean…"

Tags: literature, formality, construction

It appears to me that the construction "just because… doesn't mean…" isn't used in literature at all. Is its use limited to colloquial speech and informal writing?

Note that while some people seem to be up in arms about this construction, I am not jumping on that bandwagon. I rather side with [sober analysis](http://faculty.washington.edu/ebender/papers/bender_kathol01.pdf) <sup>[PDF]</sup> than with angry Reddit rants. So, basically, I'm just looking for a quote by Poe or Twain, though I suspect the construction is younger (is it?).

Comment: Related: [Sentence construction: just because...does not mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/sentence-construction-just-because-does-not-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found nothing from [Twain](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbs=bks:1,bkv%3aa&q=doesn-t-mean+twain+%22just+because%22+inauthor%3aTwain&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) or [Poe](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbs=bks:1,bkv%3aa&q=doesn-t-mean+twain+%22just+because%22+inauthor%3aPoe&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). However, google can help you find usage of this phrase in books sorted by [date](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22just+because%22+%22doesn%27t+mean%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FvVuTJyKOIK8lQeL7bGaDQ&ved=0CBoQpwU&source=lnt&tbs=bks:1,sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1920).

Answer (score 8):

I’ve just discovered the wonderful Corpus of Historical American English, and you, dear reader, get see the first fruits of my research there:

> Date: 1942
>   Publication information: Doubleday & Company, Inc. 1970
>   Title: Along the Street
>   Author: Struthers Burt
>
> "**Just because** I've had everything done for me **doesn't mean** I can't get along without lots of things I've been used to. The only thing I can't face doing without is you. We can manage with what I have. I know we can."

A similar construction from 1914:

> Date:  1914
>   Title:  On With Torchy
>   Author: Ford, Sewell, 1868-1946
>
> … can't give you all the details without pullin' down a subpoena from the Attorney-General's office, and I ain't anxious to crowd Willie Rockefeller, or anybody like that, out of the witness chair. But I can go as far as to state that, as near as I could dope it out, Peter K. was only standin' on his rights, and if only him and Mr. Ellins could have got together for half an hour peaceable-like things could have been squared all around. We needed Groff every tick of the clock, and **just because** he ain't always polite in statin' his views over the wire **wa'n't any first-class reason** for us extendin' him an official invitation to go sew his head in a bag. Uh-huh, them was Old Hickory's very words. I stood by while he writes the message. Then I takes it out and shows it to Piddie and grins. You should have seen Piddie's face. He turns the color of green pea soup and gasps. He's got all the fightin' qualities of…

Comment: So, once in dialogue, and once in clearly colloquial prose.

Answer (score 1):

The NOAD reports an example of sentence using *just because*, and *doesn't mean*.

> because /bəˈkɔz/ /biˈkɔz/
>   conjunction
>   for the reason that; since: *we did it because we felt it our duty* | *just because I'm inexperienced doesn't mean that I lack perception*.

Simply replacing *just because* with *since* would change the sentence to

> (*****) Since I'm inexperienced doesn't mean that I lack perception.

NOAD reports when a phrase is informal, and it doesn't do it with that sentence.

Comment: The use of "since" in that second example doesn't sound right to me. I'd be more inclined to say, "My inexperience doesn't mean that I lack perception".

Comment: I tend to agree with Steve. Another nice way would be to replace "just because" with "the fact that": "The fact that I'm inexperienced doesn't mean that I lack perception"

Comment: Or "simply because" would also be more formal.

Comment: That is because there is a _(**?**)_ before the sentence; basing on what reported on this site, it means the sentence is not correct.

Comment: More specifically, `?` means it is awkward/marginal at best, and `*` means it is definitely ungrammatical.  (This is the standard used in linguistics anyway.)

Comment: I used the example with _since_ because in such sentences _because_ means _for the reason that_, or _since_. I just wanted to point out that _because_ could not replaced with _since_ in the example used by the OP.

Comment: @Jonik, *The fact that ...* is clearly the most "logical" way to say this, if we think that language should be logical.

Comment: The usage of "since" in that example is incorrect.

Comment: @narx See the comment by Kosmonaut: _?_ means it is awkward/marginal at best, and _*_ means it is definitely ungrammatical.

Comment: You're right.  I hadn't noticed the footnote.